# word add-in, KeyDown handling on combobox in customui

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, vsto, add-in

> Blockquote

Need some help with **CustomUI** in Word add-in.
I have a

```
<combobox />
```

in my custom ui.

How can I handle <kbd>Enter</kbd> pressing by user ?
I need to perform some actions when user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> in that `ComboBox`.
Can I add `KeyDown` event somehow or maybe cast `IRibbonControl` to something useful?

**UPDATE :**

Made decision not to include that functionality. But still interested in solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even WindowSelectionChange event wont help you. It works for other Key press but not for Enter and Backspace (As I am aware of).

You have to use [low level keyboard hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

EDITED****

There is a callback when any of the key been pressed it will be called.

```
 private static IntPtr HookCallback(
                int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
            {
                if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr) WM_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                    //Check if the enter key is pressed
                    if (vkCode == (int) Keys.Enter )
                        // Do here whatever you need
                }
                return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but, that's even with that solution i wan't know when exactly  "ENTER" was pressed. Thanks fore help :)

Comment: ok, there is no focus event or something like that in Word Ribbon, so i don't know weather it was pressed in my combobox or just somewhere else. But link was helpful)

Comment: Sorry if there is any easiest please ignore this. Try using Windows Accessibility API http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f/sourcecode?fileId=22031&pathId=708905728 you can find the state of the control in ribbon.